# " Expected:) " in python code

Tags: python, self

I'm coding an `__init__()` function but I have an error which is: `Expected:)`, and further there is: `Undefined variable: self`

I really don't understand why I got this, can you help me?

My code:

```
class PVT_frame:
"Definition of PVT frame"

    def __init__(self, data_rmc['year'], ... ):

        ###TIME VALUES
        self.year = data_rmc['year']
        self.month = data_rmc['month']
        self.day = data_rmc['day']
        ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show the full stack trace. there are several problems with your code, first of all indentation..

Comment: You can't have an expression like `data_rmc['year']` inside the argument list of the method.

Comment: Slow down, read up on the basics. You'll thank me later :p

Comment: I know indentation is incorrect here, but it is on Eclipse, that's not the problem

Comment: What is `data_rmc['year']` doing in the parameter list, and what do you want with `...` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your code and everything will be fine.

```
class PVT_frame:
    """Definition of PVT frame"""

    def __init__(self, data_rmc, *args):
        self.year = data_rmc['year']
        self.month = data_rmc['month']
        self.day = data_rmc['day']
```

Another thing, use **triple double** quotes for doc string.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's perfect ! It's better with just data_rmc. And btw, I take note for the triple double, thank you.

Comment: @user2135862 Could you please accept if you don't have other question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Indent your code correctly.
2. Use `def __init__(self, data_rmc):`